# Is there a way to split a list in the following format : 'string1', 'string2', 'string3',

Tags: c#, sql, split, filtering, where-in

I need to perform a filter to my existing XtraReport and I want to see only some specific records which I have their ID's.

When I execute following code it is applied successfully.

```
XtraReportOrder report = new XtraReportOrder();
report.FilterString = "orderId IN ('11092', '11093')";
report.ShowPreviewDialog();
```

I want to use sth like this,

```
report.FilterString = "orderId IN ("+MyList.ToConvertSthConvinient+")";
```

Comment: I would consider using [string.join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Object___)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of `String.Join`, LINQ and the string interpolation feature:

```
report.FilterString = $"orderId IN ({String.Join(", ", MyList.Select(id => $"'{id}'"))})";
```